# create unique folder of each user from input and save images inside that folder using php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on project for creating Online Exam for college Entrance. I am looking for solution to upload image and create folder using user serial id as which is as per mysql database primary increment idsave the images inside the folder.

Here is my solution where images are uploaded in already created folder called uploads. How to modify this for what I required.

```html
<?php
session_start();
include('../connect.php');
$a = $_POST['name'];

// query

$file_name  = strtolower($_FILES['file']['name']);
$file_ext = substr($file_name, strrpos($file_name, '.'));
$prefix = 'your_site_name_'.md5(time()*rand(1, 9999));
$file_name_new = $prefix.$file_ext;
$path = '../uploads/'.$file_name_new;


    /* check if the file uploaded successfully */
    if(@move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $path)) {

  //do your write to the database filename and other details   
$sql = "INSERT INTO student (name,file) VALUES (:a,:h)";
$q = $db->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array(':a'=>$a,':h'=>$file_name_new));
header("location: students.php");

 }
?>
```

Comment: (1) what have you attempted? Where is your attempted code? (2) Why do you want to create a folder per user? That will get out of control quickly. If it only contains 1 image, is it worth it?

Comment: @Sean above is what I have for now which saves the image file to already created folder called upload. I want to create folder per user because it will be easy to verify their documents from image they have uploaded which they will upload their certificates. NO I"m planning to upload 4-5 images..hope that answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

First: Be careful uploading files without correctly checking it's types;

Second: As Sean mentioned, this approach may get out of control.

--

The following example changed the steps that you tried.

First insert the user to get it's ID and then create the folder under '*../uploads*' with it.

This way you **do not** need to move the file two times (move the file to *../uploads*, insert the user and then move the file again to *../uploads/userID*)

```php
<?php

...

$sql = "INSERT INTO student (name,file) VALUES (:a,:h)";
$q = $db->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array(':a'=>$a,':h'=>$file_name_new));

// Get user id
$studentId = $db->lastInsertId();

// Create path with new userId just inserted
$path = "../uploads/$studentId/";
if(!file_exists($path)) { // maybe  "&& !is_dir($path)" ?
   // IMPORTANT NOTE: the second argument is the permission of the folder. 0777 is the default and may cause security flaws
   mkdir($path, 0777, true);
}

// Move the uploaded file to new path with the userId
@move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $path.$file_name_new);
```

I think you need to check if the user already exists before inserting (but I don't know the details of your project)